# Is there any academic fields where pure mathematics (Abstract Algebra or Number theory) are applied to medical/biological studies?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

I am currently looking for applications of pure mathematics ( Especially abstract algebra or number theory) to medical studies, currently I can only think of the explore of deep learning (used in medical image analysis), design of Graph Neural Networks, and a little bit use of integer programming (Not sure if it is pure math)... Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Deep Learning does more in biology than just medical imaging. For example check out the course [Deep Learning in the Life Sciences](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLypiXJdtIca5sxV7aE3-PS9fYX3vUdIOX) which is taught by Manolis Kellis, the head of the Computational Biology Group at MIT. Manolis has a few other courses on YouTube that also look very interesting.

Comment: Regarding applications of abstract algebra or number theory in medicine or biology, I would love it if this existed, but I haven't seen any good examples.

Comment: @littleO Thanks so much for your answer! DL in the Life Sciences is indeed an interesting topic. I believe there should be some connections, but I didn't find any. I viewed some papers about DNA/RNA encoding (not sure if the term is correct... im not biology majored) with group theory, but I do not think they are deep enough that can be viewed as some "breakthrough" usage of abstract algebra... (Problem is my boss asked me to find some fields of study linking cells analysis with abstract algebra lol.

Comment: There is some algebraic topology used in neural imaging, although I'm not sure it's helped that much.

Comment: Interest rates are like epidemiology ... Let the loan payment stand in for recoveries, interest for infection passing, and so on ...

Answer (score 3):

Number theory and algebra are both important components in the mathematics of folding things. Many medical objects or devices (*e.g.* stent) need to enter the body through the smallest possible opening, and then expand into something larger, often something rigid that ideally shouldn’t be able to spontaneously recompress. Medical devices is a field that uses a lot of number theory and abstract algebra.

Answer (score 2):

There are some attempts at applying process algebras to biological systems. Have a look into Luca Cardelli's papers, such as these:

[BioAmbients: an abstraction for biological compartments](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S030439750400235X/pdf?md5=7b9ddd52130630dd99285442f9de441f&pid=1-s2.0-S030439750400235X-main.pdf)

[Brane Calculi](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-25974-9_24)

[The Cell Cycle Switch Computes Approximate Majority](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep00656)